# Mapping between structs in a loop

Tags: loops, go, struct

I have a function that does some mapping between 2 structs:

```
Struct1 => Struct2
```

where `Struct1` is as follows:

```
type Struct1 struct {
A Transaction `json:"transaction"`
B string      `json:"name"`
...

}
```

whereas `Struct2` looks like this:

```
type Struct2 struct {
C AnotherTransaction `json:"transaction"`
D string      `json:"name"`
...

}
```

I have a function that maps the "inner" type `Transaction => AnotherTransaction`, but the issue I have is that there is an outer Struct, named `Struct3` for convenience, that is as follows:

```
type Struct3 struct {
    Failed   []Struct2 `json:"failed"` // a list of transactions
    Success  []Struct2 `json:"success"`
}

func mapTo(st3 Struct3) Struct1 {
  st1 := Transaction{}
  // the mapping between A => C is quite lengthy
  st1.someField = st3.struct2.anotherField

  return st1 // now mapped

}
```

My issue is that from Struct3 I need to access each element of Struct2 and fire up the mapping function above, but I am not sure how to go about it. How can I loop through each element of `[]Struct2` append each element and **return** `Struct3` now populated with the mapping from `mapTo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the map function's argument to struct2 and loop through the struct3's fields of array from `main` function and send each of them to the `toMap` function.

```golang
func main() {
    type Struct3 struct {
        Failed   []Struct2 `json:"failed"` // a list of transactions
        Success  []Struct2 `json:"success"`
    }
    s3 := &Struct3{
        Failed: make([]Struct2, 0),
        Success: make([]Struct2, 0),
    }

    for i := range s3.Success {
        // do something with the result value
        _ = toMap(s3.Success[i])
    }

    for i := range s3.Failed {
        // do something with the result value
        _ = toMap(s3.Failed[i])
    }
}

func mapTo(st2 Struct2) Struct1 {
  st1 := Transaction{}
  // the mapping between A => C is quite lengthy
  st1.someField = st2.anotherField

  return st1 // now mapped

}
```